# How come e.preventDefault() doesn't stop the link from being followed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I stop the link from being followed (using this event handler)?

http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/rsqH7/1/

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="msg">
            <header><a href="http://cnn.com">cnn.com</a></header></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$('table').on('click', 'tr.msg header', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $el = $(e.currentTarget);
    console.log($el);
});
```

Comment: what do u mean with "being followed"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML isn’t valid; `<header>` can’t appear directly within a `<tr>`, and that’s breaking the whole thing. If you add an `alert`, you’ll notice the handler isn’t being called at all.

Inspecting the DOM gives me this:

```
<header><a href="http://cnn.com">cnn.com</a></header>
<table>…</table>
```

That’s the browser, helpful as always! [Correcting the HTML by putting adding a `<td>` fixes it.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/rsqH7/2/) (Or did you mean `<th>` instead of `<header>`?)

Comment: I had a typo. I left that out on accident, Now it works, but my real code still does not.

Comment: @chovy: What’s your real code? And does it [pass validation](http://validator.w3.org/)?

Comment: I found it. I had another event handler that was `$(document.body).on('click', 'header a', fn)` which was also triggering. I changed that one to `> header a` to fix it.